# Strom - Reliable Spout

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

How to set Strom spout as reliable
   Is there any property to set
   Is kafkaSpout reliable by default
   How to change the reliablity in kafkaSpout

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is reliable by default. Here's the code from PartitionManager class, which is responsible for reading messages from Kafka topic:

`collector.emit(tup, new KafkaMessageId(_partition, toEmit.offset()));`

As you can see the second parameter of emit method is KafkaMessageId. You can pass message id in your spouts in the similar way. Message id can be ordinary integer.

Comment: Thanks, btw, How to set my kafkaSpout as unreliable.. and for the normal spout also how to set that as reliable or unreliable.